# How to reflect objects on one artboard onto another in Sketch?

Tags: artboard, ios, template-design, sketch-app

I created a new file from *iOS App Icon* template in Sketch, and put some objects on the largest artboard there, which is 1024 x 1024 size named as `iTunesArtwork@2x`. However, you still have to put the same objects to the different size of artboards such as `Icon-60@2x`, when you like to check how it is displayed in the different size of icons.

What I would like to achieve is something like that pushing some commands reflects the design on the largest artboard to all the other artboards. Is it possible to do that? I even don't know why it creates so many different size of templates if you cannot reflect one artboard onto another.

I use the latest version of Sketch 3, which is 3.2.2 at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer: No

## Long answer: Symbols *should* do it

You can create a symbol out of any group of objects (except those containing other symbols) to standardize your doc. Unfortunately, Sketch takes that standardization very seriously. Any changes you make to an instance of the symbol will affect all other instances, including scale.

As of the latest version, you *can* apply shadow and opacity changes to a single instance. I suspect Bohemian will be looking into variable scale in the near future, as it remains one of the biggest advantages Illustrator has over Sketch today.

## Bad workaround

The one feature you can exploit is Sketch's fantastic exporting. Because you can run a quick export and overwrite ...

1. Set up your main art.
2. Add export settings for every size you want.
3. Dump them all out to a directory.
4. Set up a simple html file that displays them for you.

Now, with extraordinary inelegance, you can work on some changes, export all (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>), and go refresh your handy little web page.

If you're really cool, you'd just write that whole process as a self-aware **[plug-in](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/developer/)** that builds the page and then knows to just update the resources. Then come back here and share it (^_-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question; If the only difference is size, you don't need different artboards, as the artboard's export function allows you to choose the relative (proportional) size of the final artwork.

Could you clarify or did I indirectly answer your question?

Take care,

Comment: No, I want to duplicate objects on one artboard to all the other artboards, with the size being adjusted to those artboards.